# How to check the direction of the sending and receiving processes correct when several processes communicate in halo exchange

Tags: c++, mpi

When all processes participate in halo exchange, this is how we check for correctness

```
void checkHaloExchangeDirection(
    const Array<int> &send_process_index, const Array<int> &recv_process_index, MPI_Comm comm)
{
    const int process_index = toolbox::MPI::getProcessIndex(comm);
    const int process_num = toolbox::MPI::getNumberOfProcess(comm);

    const int root = 0;

    Array<Array<int> > send;
    Array<Array<int> > recv;
    gatherScalarArray(send_process_index, send, root, comm);
    gatherScalarArray(recv_process_index, recv, root, comm);

    MPI_Barrier(comm);
    if (process_index == root)
    {
        toolbox::SparseAdjacencyMatrix matrix(process_num);
        // flag all send direction
        for (int i = 0; i < process_num; i++)
        {
            const Array<int> &it_send = send[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < it_send.getSize(); j++)
            {
                matrix.flagEdge(i, it_send[j]);
            }
        }
        // check all recv
        for (int i = 0; i < process_num; i++)
        {
            const Array<int> &it_recv = recv[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < it_recv.getSize(); j++)
            {
                if (matrix.isExistEdge(it_recv[j], i) == false)
                {
                    toolbox::Abort::abort("halo exchange direction error.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    MPI_Barrier(comm);
}
```

Now, only part of processes participate in halo exchange, this check will failed because of the gather and MPI_Barrier operations.

What can I do now to make sure it's right? Thank you for your time and appreciate it if you can give me any suggestion.

Comment: one option is to update your check subroutine so that all the ranks of the communicator invoke it and send/recv zero bytes if they did not participate to the actual halo exchange.